# Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IQueryCollection.get_Item(System.String)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When I try to run a HttpTrigger Azure Function V2 (Visual studio project) it blows up when I try to retrieve the Query part of the request url.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{

    string clientId = req.Query["clientid"].ToString();
```

Method not found:
 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IQueryCollection.get_Item(System.String)

I looked at this this post in github https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/774 and downgraded to 2.1 Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and it makes no difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using ? which version of the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` are you using ? Could add your `csproj`file also ?

Comment: Could you share more code or share what your code did? Cause I test local the `Configuration` package works well.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

figured it out, turns out one of  the NUGET packages installed was a preview version.